# Setting default image to the image field which are null values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp.net program in which images are stored in sql database as byte format. when I search each item the value will be displayed in the gridview with images. Some of the product didn't have image and the value is null. So I need to set a default image for the null value. How can I do this? pls help.
This is my code

```html
 <img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<%# Eval("img") != System.DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("img")) : string.Empty %>' alt="image" height="250px" width="275px"/>
```

Comment: Inside where is that code ? (GridView ?)

Comment: yes inside the gridview

Answer (score 1):

Because the `<%# ...%>` is actually render on page something, is difficult to make complicate logic action in one line, so what I do is to call a function, and inside that function I implemented my logic, and here is an example base on your question:

On asp.net and inside GridView

```
<asp:TemplateField >
    <ItemTemplate >
      <%#GetImage(Container.DataItem)%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and on code behind

```
protected string GetImage(object oItem) 
{
    // read the data from database
    var cImgSrc = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "img") as byte[];

    // if we do not have any image, return some default.
    if(cImgSrc == System.DBNull)
        return "<img src=\"empty.gif\">"
    else
        // format and render back the image
        return String.Format("<img src=\"data:image/jpg;base64,{0}\" alt=\"image\" height=\"250px\" width=\"275px\"/>", 
            Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])cImgSrc));
}
```

Comment: Sir, it shows error on return "<img src=\"empty.gif\">"

Comment: @vishnusuresh What the error says ?. Beside the error, please I can not debug your code, this is the main idea, you need to take it and go one step forward and adapt it to your project.

Answer (score 0):

**RowDataBound ??**

**Use SQL View**

- you can use `RowDataBound`, **But `RowDataBound` is triggered for every row** and it results to slowdown the web application. So, instead for `RowDataBound` use **SQL View**.
- for your current scenario - create one `sql view` with `ISNULL(,)` as below.

`select col1, col2, ISNULL(ImgCol, '<img src=\"empty.gif\">') AS ImgCol from tableName`

and bind above query to your `C# DataTable` and bind that `DataTable` with your `asp GridView`